# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00947: not enough values

Tags: oracle, python-2.7, cx-oracle

I have a table:

```
create table employee (
employee_id  NUMBER NOT NULL,
name   VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
notes      VARCHAR2(4000),
created_by varchar2(255) not null,
created_at date default sysdate not null,
updated_by varchar2(255) not null,
updated_at date default sysdate not null,
PRIMARY KEY(vendor_id)
);
```

so when I insert from SQL developer:

```
insert into employee(employee_id, name,notes) values(1,'xyz','test');
```

it auto populates create_by, created_at, updated_at and updated_by.

row gets inserted successfully.

Whereas if I try to insert using cx_Oracle module in python,

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee VALUES (:employee_id,:name,:notes)",
                            {
                             'employee_id' : max_value,
                             'name' : each_vendor,
                             'notes' : 'test'
                             }
                            )
```

it throws error saying not enough values.

Why do I get this error? How can I solve it?

Comment: are you sure that it works in sql developer? You haven't specified any default values for the created_by or updated_by columns, so I would expect it to fail no matter where you ran that insert statement from.

Comment: Have you checked the values for your variables?
max_value and each_vendor

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple, and has nothing to do with python.  Your 2 `insert` statements are very different.

In the 1st, you explicitly name the columns you intend to provide values for: `(employee_id, name,notes)`. However, in the `insert` statement used from Python, you don't specify the 3 columns by name.  As a result, your `insert` statement expects you to provide the values for *all* columns in the table.

The fix: explicitly name the 3 columns:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO employee (employee_id, name, notes) VALUES (:employee_id,:name,:notes)",
                            {
                             'employee_id' : max_value,
                             'name' : each_vendor,
                             'notes' : 'test'
                             }
                            )
```